# Use contract from outside contract folder in hardhat test

Tags: hardhat, mocha

When I try to import a contract from other artifacts folders or node modules into the dapp test using

```
this.LinkToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/LinkToken.sol')
```

it generates an error saying that it could not be found, I've gessed that it just looks in the artifacts/contracts folder.

I've also tried `getContractAt` and it generates the same result

Is it possible to import a contract outside of it?, thanks

The specific error is `HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/LinkToken.sol" not found.`

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In you `hardhat.config.js` add this:

```
paths: {
   sources: "./<YOUR_CONTRACT_FOLDER>",
}
```

Comment: How do you add a contract folder that is compiled and used only for unit tests, but not for `npx hardhat flatten` etc.?